# xtics position by custom label

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I've been trying to put some custom labels in my `bar` plotting, but what I found is that for some reason, my custom labels are starting from the center. I'd like to start in the left position. I'm not using the artist layer.

```
df_train_sex_female_die.Pclass.value_counts().plot(kind="bar")
plt.title("Female die distribution by Social Class", fontsize="16")
plt.ylabel("Number of people", fontsize="16")
custom_labels = ['Low', 'medium', 'High']
plt.xlabel("Social class classification", fontsize="16")
plt.xticks([1, 2, 3], custom_labels, rotation='horizontal')
```

[image]

Comment: `plt.xticks([0,1,2], custom_labels,...)`?

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
plt.xticks([0, 1, 2], custom_labels, rotation='horizontal')
```

Comment: Thanks!! I was not realizing i was wrong in my indexing position